# Загрузить текущую сцену Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как загрузить текущую сцену Unity? Пробовал так

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene);
```

Пишет, что метод групп не может преобразовать в строку.

В старых версиях вроде как можно было

```
Application.LoadScene(EditorApplication.currentScene);
```

Но это устаревший код. 
Как сейчас перезапустить сцену с начала или просто получить её  номер?

Comment: Уже был ответ на Ваш вопрос кажется [это то что Вам нужно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609457/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%B2-unity-5-3).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По идее `GetActiveScene` - это метод. А вы обращаетесь к нему как к свойству.
То есть, минимум, нужно писать так: `SceneManager.GetActiveScene()`. Это как вступление-отступление.

Далее. Метод `GetActiveScene` возвращает объект типа [Scene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.html) у которого, как можно увидеть пройдя по ссылке в документацию, есть поле [name](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene-name.html), которое возвращает имя сцены.

Соответственно, зная это, вам нужно написать так:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
```