# Как загрузить новый уровень в Unity 5.3+?

Tags: c#, unity3d

До версии 5.3 я мог спокойно написать:

```
Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
```

и загрузить уровень по имени или индексу.

Но теперь использовать этот способ не работает, пишет ошибку:

> UnityEngine.Application.LoadLevel(int) is obsolete: `Use SceneManager.LoadScene'

Что это за менеджер сцен такой? Как теперь получить, например, текущую сцену и загрузить её?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Юнити развивается и что-то переделывается, улучшается. Теперь за загрузку уровней (сцен) отвечает как раз логичный **[SceneManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html)**, а не аж целое приложение (Application).

Менеджер теперь в своем пространстве имен. Подключается:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```

Пример использования:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Example
{
    public void ReloadCurrentScene()
    {
        // Получаем имя текущей сцены
        string sceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;    
        // Загружаем её саму родимую
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
}
```

Т.е. **[SceneManager.LoadScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html)** теперь загружает сцену по имени или по индексу, **[SceneManager.GetActiveScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene.html)** — получает информацию об активной сцене, в том числе её имя (список переменных сцены: [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.html)). Ну и еще небольшая кучка разных методов.